# How to not using inner select

Tags: sql, select

```
select  student_surname, 
        student_name,
        student_recordbook,
        student_kurs,
        student_state,
        student_dep_id,
        student_kafedra_id
from
     student
where student_studgroups = (select studgroups_number
                            from studgroups 
                              join study on study_studgroups_id = studgroups_id
                            where studgroups_year != study_kurs
                              and study_state_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,21,22,23,24));
```

I need to optimize it without a subquery.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to optimize?

Comment: Instead of image if you put actual code here then it will easily understandable

Comment: What's wrong with the sub-query? Note that your query will fail if the sub-query returns more than one row. You might want to change the `student_studgroups = (` to `student_studgroups IN (`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below-

```
select * from student a 
inner join student_groups b on a.student_studgroup=b.studgroups_number
inner join study on study_studgroup_id=stud_Group_id
where (your condition --)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
select * 
from student s 
  join studgroups sg on (s.studygroups = sg.studgroups_number) 
  join study st on (sg.studgroupys_id = st.study_studgroups_id) 
where sg.studgroups_year !=s.study_kurs 
  and s.study_state_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,21,22,23,24);
```

What I did here, I joined all three tables with the help of primary and foriegn key.

So you can get the same result using JOIN what you get from using subquery.

Comment: That returns a different result.